# Getting error when trying to import formsy-react. Cannot read property 'React' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, formsy-react

**Note**: I made a git repo so one can replicate the issue
https://github.com/giovannicode/formsy-import-test

I am trying to use the formsy-react library for a react js project.

But I'm having trouble importing the file. I'm new to webpack and ES6 so I'm not sure if I'm missing something important.
Here is my .babelrc file:

```
{
"presets": [
"es2015", "react"
 ]
}
```

Here is my webpack.config.js file:

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  //externals: 'react',
  entry: {
    'app': './app.jsx',
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "[name].js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        include: __dirname,
        loader: "babel-loader"
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

And here is my app.jsx file:

```
import React from 'react';  
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import {Formsy} from 'formsy-react';

var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="commentBox">
        Hello, world! I am a CommentBox.
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <CommentBox />,
  document.getElementById('react-content')
);
```

If I comment out the formsy-react import, the app will work fine.
But when I add the import I get the **follow error in the browser**:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'React' of undefined
```

The app will compile without error through webpack though so im not sure what's going on.

**Note**: I made a git repo so one can replicate the issue
https://github.com/giovannicode/formsy-import-test

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to import dependencies in two ways,

module import from ES6 and

`import Formsy from 'forms-react'`

and loading the module with require

`var React = require('react');`

watching your code you probably want to use ES6 syntax

```
import React from 'react'
import Formsy from 'forms-react'
```

Comment: Hey Alejandro thanks for the reply. I tried what you suggested, but I still got the same error. I also tried it both using the `var x= require(''x")` syntax, but i still got the same error.

Comment: Ok, first i think you already installed React dependencies via NPM, for using webpack you will need an Entry point, a file usually called "index.js".

So in your `entry {}` object you should reference index.js (entry point) eg:

`entry: {
    './app/index.js'
}`

you can have many entry points, but make sure you have array syntax
`entry: [ 'file ', ' anotherFile' ]`.

// entry file for web pack

`import React from 'react'
 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
 import routes from './config/routes'

ReactDOM.render(
    routes,
    document.getElementById('app')
)`

Comment: you can also create react apps with no configuration, if you are learning its awesome 

https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/22/create-apps-with-no-configuration.html

Comment: Hey Alejandro thanks for the help. I did not have any luck getting the app to run, but I created a test repo to replicate my issue. Hopefully, this will help someone understand my issue better. https://github.com/giovannicode/formsy-import-test